# Processing embedded lists inside dict variables in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I got the example code in Ansible:

```
    - name: testing
      hosts: localhost
      vars:
        svc:
          https: ['tcp/443']
          app_svc: ['tcp/5543', 'udp/5543', 'tcp/3100']
      tasks:
      - name: print
        debug:
          msg: port={{item.key}} value={{item.value}}

        with_dict:
         - "{{svc}}"
```

```
And this outputs to:
```

> ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=None) => {
>          "msg": "port=app_svc value=[u'tcp/5543', u'udp/5543', u'tcp/3100']"
>      }
>      ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=None) => {
>          "msg": "port=https value=[u'tcp/443']"
>      }

What I would like to achieve is, when there is more than one element in list of values it would split like this:

```
 - name=https, prot=tcp, port=443
 - name=app_svc, prot=tcp, port=5543
 - name=app_svc, prot=udp, port=5543
 - name=app_svc, prot=tcp, port=3100
```

with_dict stanza only displays me a whole list and I couldn't find a way do do it differently. Is it possible to do it like that without reorganizing the var section? Thanks in advance for input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see the syntax errors run

```
# ansible-lint <YOUR-PLAYBOOK>
```

Correct syntax should be

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    svc:
      https: ['tcp/443']
      app_svc: ['tcp/5543', 'udp/5543', 'tcp/3100']
  tasks:
    - name: print
      debug:
        msg: "port={{ item.key }} value={{ item.value }}"
      with_dict: "{{ svc }}"
```

gives

```
"msg": "port=app_svc value=[u'tcp/5543', u'udp/5543', u'tcp/3100']"
"msg": "port=https value=[u'tcp/443']"
```

Change the loop

```
- name: print
  debug:
    msg: "name={{ item.0.key }},
          prot={{ item.1.split('/')[0] }},
          port={{ item.1.split('/')[1] }}"
  loop: "{{ lookup('subelements', svc|dict2items, 'value') }}"
```

to get the format

```
"msg": "name=app_svc, prot=tcp, port=5543"
"msg": "name=app_svc, prot=udp, port=5543"
"msg": "name=app_svc, prot=tcp, port=3100"
"msg": "name=https, prot=tcp, port=443"
```

[dict2items](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#dict-filter) is available since version 2.6 . Without "*dict2items*" transform the data first. See below (not tested).

```
https:
  - {key: 'https', value: ['tcp/443']}
  - {key: 'app_svc', value: ['tcp/5543', 'udp/5543', 'tcp/3100']}
```

Comment: Ooops, sorry. That's because the code was copied somehow incorrectly from the file. Thanks for pointing that out. The question in topic still remains open.

Comment: It works for v 2.6 . Unfortunately I do not have a luxury to use such version. Any other option for v 2.4 (no dict2items filter)? Sorry for not being precise regarding the version. Seems like in this case version matters.

Comment: "A luxury to use such version"? A controller might be a flexible standalone host. What might be the reason not to upgrade?

Comment: Out of date local Jenkins build server :)

Comment: Reorganizing in such structure works, I tried a similar approach before. I'd prefer to have prettier definition but oh well, I must be happy with the current solution at least for now.